# how to get string first character and after (-) first character uppercase in php?

Tags: php

I want to change a string in uppercase. I am successfully doing it but I am able to do only first character and I want after(-) the first character also change.

```
$res = "mogli-story";
$strFinal = ucfirst($res);
```

Then the output is:

```
Mogli-story
```

I want to get output like:

```
Mogli-Story (First letter capital and the First letter after (-) capital)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
$strFinal = implode("-", array_map(ucfirst, explode("-", $res)))
```

This splits the string at each `-` character, uses `ucfirst` on each string in the resulting array, then joins them back together with `-`s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if (-) not in the string? Because the content is dynamic. It could be story2 instead of mogli-story

Comment: Then it should just capitalise the first letter, as I believe you want. By all means test it on such a value.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account when there is no character

```
function headcase($str,$sym){
    if (!empty($sym)){
        $str1 = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $sym));
        $str2 = substr($str, strpos($str, $sym) + 1);  
        $final = ucfirst($str1).$sym.ucfirst($str2);
    }else{
        $final = ucfirst($str);

    }
    return $final;
}
echo headcase("mogli2","");
echo headcase("mogli-story","-");
```